# What value of ANOVA F-Value is significant

Tags: anova, feature-selection, scikit-learn

I'm using ANOVA F-Value from Scikit-learn ([link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.f_classif.html#sklearn.feature_selection.f_classif)) to find importance of features in a machine learning task. I have numeric feature and binary classification. I'm also filtering the features whose p-value is > 0.05, but I don't know what value for the ANOVA F-Value is good enough?

Comment: Leaving aside whether what you're doing makes sense, which F corresponds to a given p-value is a function of the two degrees-of-freedom parameters. There's no single F value that goes with $p\approx 0.05$

Comment: Could you explain why this approach is not making sense? If F-value is not suitable for feature importance, why it's included in the scikit-learn?

Comment: As for why it's there, that would best be asked by the people that decided to include it, but variable selection by backward elimination based on p-value is not a great way to choose variables, and p-value doesn't really measure importance. Some of the issues with such selection approaches I assume you're avoiding via cross validation or something similar, though.

Comment: I'm only filtering out features whose p-value is less that 0.05 because we don;t have sufficient confidence in the the F-Value for those features. After the filtering, I'm looking at the F-Value and select those that I think are more important (based on some buseiness logic). does this make sense?

Answer (score 2):

> I'm also filtering the features whose p-value is > 0.05

Don't do that. $p$-values of coefficients are a bad way to select models or features because they don't directly quantify any useful measures of model quality. Besides, while obtaining $p < α$ tells you that a null hypothesis is infeasible, obtaining $p > α$ doesn't much support its feasibility, so when a test fails to reject the null hypothesis, it doesn't tell you anything.

Comment: you mean I should not put any condition on p-value? how should I choose the best features then?

Comment: @H.Z. [The Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_selection) is a good place to start. But it's also worth considering whether you need to do feature selection in the first place.

Comment: I need to do feature selection and scikit-learn provides this ANOVA f-Value as a feature selection technique, any comment?

Comment: @H.Z. I disagree with the sklearn people that an ANOVA is a good way to do feature selection, yes.